# Out of the Money Puts and American/European style options

Tags: options

How about exercising a put option Out of the Money?

Buying a put option at a price of 226$ with a strike price of 320$ on a XYZ company with a stock valued at 350$?

Wouldn't that make sense?

Also, how can you know if you're buying an American or European stock option?

Answer (score 1):

It makes no sense at all.

1. Why would you exercise a long put to sell the stock at $320 when you can sell the stock at $350?
2. Why would you throw away $226 of time premium by exercising?

Most indexes are European style.  Equities are American style.